# Export data in .csv format by using script

Tags: lotus-notes

is there a method to export all data in a specific view with A LOTS of columns by using script language ?

i use the following code to extract dinamically the titles of the view

```
Dim column As NotesViewColumn
For n=0 To (view.ColumnCount-1)
    Set column = view.Columns( n )
    If n= (view.ColumnCount-1) Then
        titles=titles+column.Title
    Else
        titles=titles+column.Title+","
    End If
Next
```

but i don't know ho to get all columns value data without insert in the code "fixed" data like the fileds name.
it's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted some code on my blog a while back:
http://blog.texasswede.com/export-notes-view-to-excel-with-multi-value-fields/

It shows you how to export a view both as HTML as well as in CSV format.

Here is what your code would look like if you use the class I posted on the blog:

```
Dim csv As CSVData
Dim outfile As String

Set csv = New CSVData("DominoServer/YourDomain", "names.nsf", "People\By Last Name")
'*** Create CSV file from view
outfile = "c:\ExportTest.csv"
Open outfile For Output As #1
ForAll row In csv.CSVArray()
    Print #1, row
End ForAll
Close #1
```

Enjoy!

Comment: In lotus notes 6.5 i can't use "dim csv as csvdata". do you have another solution to export the view content ? the prerogative on your blog is valid also for me " Some columns contained multiple values, but not on all documents"

Comment: Did you include the script library? Did you read the blog entry?

Comment: ops ! i haven't include the library ! thank's now it work !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ColumnValues` property of either the [NotesDocument](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDOCUMENT_CLASS.html) or [NotesViewEntry](http://brunnur.stjr.is/help/help85_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/75eed1e15c73ec7285257607005fcbc3?OpenDocument) class. To use the former, iterate through the `NotesDocument` objects in a `NotesView` object using `GetFirstDocument()` and `GetNextDocument()`. To use the latter, use `CreateViewNav` (or one of the related methods) in the `NotesView` class, then iterate through the `NotesViewEntry` objects via GetFirst() and GetNext().

Comment: i use ColumnValues property of NotesDocument. Great Solution ! thank's

Comment: but your solution is valid only if in my view i there are no-multivalue field. and if i have some column that can be contain multi value fileds ?

Comment: i use                                                                                                                      Dim multivaluefield As Variant
multivaluefield=doc.ColumnValues(n)
For i=0 To Ubound(multivaluefield)
  record=record &  {"} & multivaluefield(i) 
Next

Comment: Since multi-valued fields can be handled in a couple of different ways in a Notes view, and also different ways you might want your multi-value fields to be treated in the CSV, there really is no one-size-fits-all solution for exporting from the view with multi-value fields. See here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/bpmpblog.nsf/dx/multiple-values-in-multiple-rows-in-multiple-columns