Export nsf file using ibm tool wizard file-export option
I tried exporting nsf file specific views etc using file _export option in ibm tool wizard. unfortunately I'm able to export the structure of the view in csv file format but not the contents. how to export content in csv?

Please specify what version of Notes you are using, and specify exactly what options you are selecting in the export dialog box. A screen shot would not hurt.

I performed the below steps:Open the IBM Lotus Notes application on your system.
Click on the File button and select Open.
Browse to select the NSF file from its location.
Click on the File option and choose Export.
In the next window, select CSV (comma-separated value) as the file format. Version. 9.

kindly let me know if you need any details.

Do you see the documents displayed in the view when you open the NSF file?

Yes I see documents displayed in the view when I open NSF file.

And all you get is the header line in the CSV? No data at all?

Yes only header but no data in csv

There are a few things I would look at. 1. Do you have access to the documents? I.e., can you open and view them? 2. Has encryption been used in the documents? I.e. is there a $Seal item in the list in document properties, or do you get a message when you open them telling them that you do not have the correct key?  3. Is there a problem that is specific to your Notes client? I.e.,  does this happen with other NSF files, too? And is there another computer with a Notes client that you can try this on?

I have access to the documents. Yes I can open and view them. No encryption is used in documents.i tried opening notes client in different computer but no luck.i tested for other nsf files but it looks to be same issue i.e, content is not getting exported  but structure is exported.Thanks

Note:Structure is exported i.e.header line in the csv

Im not sure just checking to understand if we need to enable any settings options in the ibm dialog export include options etc inorder to export contents if there are anything such kind of options

The default selection is  "All Documents". This should export everything in the view that you have permission to read. If you change it to "Selected documents", it should export only the documents you have selected, which will be shown with checkmarks next to them on the left margin of the view . Note that if the view is categorized, selecting a collapsed category does not select the documents in that category.

Thanks for the details. I'm not still able to export contents and let me know if there are something i am Missing inorder to export nsf file data into CSV .

There is only one more thing I can think of. Actually, it is two things that are kind of related. I don't know they have any impact on export, but maybe they do,  Check document properties and look for an item called $KeepPrivate. I don't know if it blocks export, but it might block it for any document that has that item.

The second thing is to look at the database ACL. There is a checkbox labeled "Replicate of Copy Documents". Note that this checkbox is potentially different for every entry in the ACL, so you must determine which entry applies to you and see if it is checked for you. If it is not checked, then perhaps it is blocking the export.

Thanks for the details. I tried both the above steps but no luck so far in exporting the contents. One is to check document properties and looked for an item $keepprivate and its not listed. Next thing is to looked at database ACL and checkbox label seems to be checked replicate of copy documents for each entries .

I would appreciate if you please guide if anything else blocking to export contents. Thanks in advance.

I'm not sure if this is been blocking export but please correct with below understanding This method of ibm dialog options file -export works flawlessly until you hit a text field that contains a comma or tab, then the export fails.

How to ensure if the custom notes nsf applications that we are trying to export is clean and file export dialog tool method works as expected

The export feature works. It has worked for more than 30 years. If there are problems like commas or quotation marks in fields that you are exporting, you need to account for that in the column value formulas before you do the export.
That said, I usually do not rely on this feature. Instead, I have my own set of LotusScript agents with code that does the export. It sometimes needs to be customized for the job, as some situations may need special handling.

If you want to use a LotusScript solution, you could try starting with Karl-Henry's solution, which he describes in an answer to a question eight years ago.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357371/export-data-in-csv-format-by-using-script

Appreciate your valuable guidance.Thanks a lot.

Unfortunately,I'm not having Lotus script skills hence I'm exploring to export via ibm tool dialog positively.

In HCL Notes and Domino, a form defines how documents are displayed to the user and how the form's data items are stored.
When user open a new document, the form that defines that document is used to render a page on the client UI. When users save the new document, the data from the UI is used to create the document in the database (.nsf file) according to the data definitions on the form. Likewise when users open an existing document, the data is rendered on the client UI according to the data definitions on the form.
A view reports documents in columns and rows. Each row of a view represents one document.
As documented in "Exporting views", you can export a view to an ASCII file, a worksheet, a tabular text file, or a structured text file. (emphasis mine). When exporting the view, only the data visible in the view is exported, not all the data stored in the document.
What you are looking for (also indicated by your other questions), is a way to export HCL Notes documents to a CSV, for which there is no built-in functionality.
